# ReleaseHold NIntegrate after Replace variable

Tags: numerical-integration, replacement, hold

I would like to calculate the sum of square of two integral(Ex and Ey). I first hold this two integral because two variables(tx, ty) are not specified.Then, I replace tx,ty and releasehold $Ex^2+Ey^2$. I get the error:

NIntegrate::
inumr: The integrand has evaluated to non-numerical values for all sampling points in the region with boundarie

`myPre2[gamma_, lambda_, alpha_, r0_] :=
 Module[{efR = gamma*lambda, k = 2*Pi/gamma, 
   betta = Sqrt[1 - 1/gamma^2], c = 299792458, Ex, ExItgd, EyItgd, Ey,
    phi, x, y, tx, ty},
  phi = k*(r0 - x*Sin[tx] - 
      y*(Cos[ty]*Sin[alpha + ty] - Sin[alpha]/betta) + 
      1/(2*r0)*(x^2*Cos[tx]^2 + 
         y^2*(1 - Cos[tx]^2*Sin[alpha + ty]^2)) - 
      x*y*Sin[2*tx]*Sin[alpha + ty]);
  ExItgd = (x/Sqrt[x^2 + y^2*Cos[alpha]^2])*
    BesselK[1, 
     2*Pi/(betta*gamma*lambda)*Sqrt[x^2 + y^2*Cos[alpha]^2]]*
    Exp[I*phi];
  EyItgd = (BesselK[1, 
         2*Pi/(betta*gamma*lambda)*Sqrt[x^2 + y^2*Cos[alpha]^2]]/
        Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 Cos[alpha]^2]*(y*Cos[alpha]^2 + 
         x*Tan[tx] Sin[alpha + ty]) - 
      I/gamma*BesselK[0, 
        2*Pi/(betta*gamma*lambda^2)*Sqrt[x^2 + y^2*Cos[alpha]^2]]*
       Sin[alpha])*Exp[I*phi];
  Ex = Cos[alpha + ty]*
    Hold@NIntegrate[ExItgd, {x, -efR, efR}, {y, -efR, efR}];
  Ey = Cos[tx]*Hold@NIntegrate[EyItgd, {x, -efR, efR}, {y, -efR, efR}];
  ReleaseHold[(Abs[Ex]^2 + Abs[Ey]^2) /. {tx -> 0.5, ty -> 0.5}]
  ]`

```
myPre2[5, 1000*^-8, 0, 1*^-6]
```

All the variables for the integrand are already specified. Why I still get this error?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: @MichaelE2 It works, thanks for your help!

Comment: You're welcome. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code

```
Hold@NIntegrate[ExItgd, {x, -efR, efR}, {y, -efR, efR}]
```

holds `ExItgd` literally as a symbol.  So the replacement `... /. {tx -> 0.5, ty -> 0.5}` has no effect.  You need to inject (or write) the code for `ExItgd` (and `EyItgd`) into the held integrals (resp.) in some way.  This is a typical use of [`With`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/With.html).

```
myPre2[gamma_, lambda_, alpha_, r0_] := 
 Module[{efR = gamma*lambda, k = 2*Pi/gamma, 
   betta = Sqrt[1 - 1/gamma^2], c = 299792458, Ex, ExItgd, EyItgd, Ey,
    phi, x, y, tx, ty}, 
  phi = k*(r0 - x*Sin[tx] - 
      y*(Cos[ty]*Sin[alpha + ty] - Sin[alpha]/betta) + 
      1/(2*r0)*(x^2*Cos[tx]^2 + 
         y^2*(1 - Cos[tx]^2*Sin[alpha + ty]^2)) - 
      x*y*Sin[2*tx]*Sin[alpha + ty]);
  ExItgd = (x/Sqrt[x^2 + y^2*Cos[alpha]^2])*
    BesselK[1, 
     2*Pi/(betta*gamma*lambda)*Sqrt[x^2 + y^2*Cos[alpha]^2]]*
    Exp[I*phi];
  EyItgd = (BesselK[1, 
         2*Pi/(betta*gamma*lambda)*Sqrt[x^2 + y^2*Cos[alpha]^2]]/
        Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 Cos[alpha]^2]*(y*Cos[alpha]^2 + 
         x*Tan[tx] Sin[alpha + ty]) - 
      I/gamma*BesselK[0, 
        2*Pi/(betta*gamma*lambda^2)*Sqrt[x^2 + y^2*Cos[alpha]^2]]*
       Sin[alpha])*Exp[I*phi];
  With[{ex = ExItgd, ey = EyItgd},
   Ex = Cos[alpha + ty]*
     Hold@NIntegrate[ex, {x, -efR, efR}, {y, -efR, efR}];
   Ey = Cos[tx]*Hold@NIntegrate[ey, {x, -efR, efR}, {y, -efR, efR}]
   ];
  ReleaseHold[(Abs[Ex]^2 + Abs[Ey]^2) /. {tx -> 0.5, ty -> 0.5}]]
```

Then

```
myPre2[5, 1000*^-8, 0, 1*^-6]
(*
  ...some convergence warnings...
  5.8686*10^-18
*)
```